# Cannot authenticate new WiFi connection any longer

Tags: wireless

When trying to connect to a new WiFi connection, the "connect" button is grayed out and the tooltip says:

"Either a password is missing or the connection is invalid. In the latter case, you have to edit the connection with nm-connection-editor first."

Starting nm-connection-editor and chosing the respective new connection, the "save" button is grayed out and it says:

"Cannot save connection due to error: Invalid setting Wi-Fi Security: invalid wpa-psk: invalid key-length 0. Must be [8,63] bytes or 64 hex digits"

This also happens when being root.

Existing networks behave like always.

I use the newest Ubuntu release and openbox. It used to work until recently and I have previously set up connections that work (no grayed out buttons).

Answer (score 1):

This must be a bug.

Work-around: Manually enter the Wi-Fi password into the respective file under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` (see existing connection files there for reference).

With this, the connection can be activated and edited (no grayed-out buttons).